# New motherboard no LED / no response: What can be done?

Tags: motherboard, computer-building

I'm struggling to get my son’s PC working again. The motherboard is a Gigabyte H410M H V2 (rev 1.7).

Okay, so a new GPU required a new PSU which required a new motherboard which required a new casing, so yeah, not feeling brilliant.

Triple-checked cabled which seems correct but no fans spinning, no action what so ever.

So to the questions.

- Can a motherboard somehow be validated *without* CPU/RAM/HDD just to make sure it's not dead?  (can't find a single status led on the motherboard. The PSU (validated on another motherboard) won't start on power-on.
- Not sure if the motherboard supports CPU. Socket 1200, CPU i5-11400F. The Gigabyte site says "(Please refer "CPU Support List" for more information.)" but can't find the link.

Comment: No fans spinning on power up usually means PSU not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Gigabyte H410M H V2 (rev 1.7)](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/H410M-H-V2-rev-17/sp#sp) supports:

> (...) **10th Generation** Intel® Core™ i9 processors/Intel® Core™ i7 processors/Intel® Core™ i5 processors/Intel® Core™ i3 processors/Intel® Pentium® processors/Intel® Celeron® processors in the LGA1200 package

The [Intel® Core™ i5-11400F](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/212271/intel-core-i511400f-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz/specifications.html) is a **11th Generation** Intel CPU.

So no, it won't work in that motherboard, according to the vendor.

[Manual](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_h410m-h-v2_e_1201_230220.pdf?v=9e418bbd67ff0f13c8b7b64f7cec42e8)